# Active record query to get the count for nested associations in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

How to write an `ActiveRecord` query to get the number of `patients` that share an `appointment` (`physician` can have more than one `appointments`)

```
class Hospital < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :patients
  has_many :physicians
end

class Physician < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :patients, through: :appointments
  belongs_to :hospital
end

class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :physician
  belongs_to :patient
  belongs_to :hospital
end

class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :physicians, through: :appointments
  belongs_to :hospital
end
```

I can get it like `Patient.first.hospital.appointments`. But really need to write a clean activerecord query and also where hospital_id is not null

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to do multiple nested joins with some conditions. This is how it is done cleanly:-

```
Patient.joins(:appointments => [:physician,:hospital]).where(patients:{<condition_hash_for_patient>},physicians:{<condition_hash_for_physician>},hospitals:{<condition_hash_for_hospital>})
```

Comment: Thanks Rohan. What about the condition_hashes for?

Comment: Whatever conditions you want to put on them. For example, .where(patients:{name:'vinay'}, physician:{id: 1})

Comment: Is it possible to get `id not nil` into those condition lists?

Comment: yes, using .where.not(id:nil) ........you can cascade two seperate where like this .where(patients:{name:'vinay'}, physician:{id: 1}).where.not(hospitals:{id:nil}) .

Comment: Hope its my last doubt. I want to use the appointments_condition_hash. When I tried that I got ActiveRecord nil as a result.

Comment: same as other models,for example :- Patient.joins(:appointments => [:physician,:hospital]).where(patients:{id:1},hospitals:{id:1},appointments:{id:1}) will result in query  SELECT "patients".* FROM "patients" INNER JOIN "appointments" ON "appointments"."patient_id" = "patients"."id" INNER JOIN "physicians" ON "physicians"."id" = "appointments"."physician_id" INNER JOIN "hospitals" ON "hospitals"."id" = "appointments"."hospital_id" WHERE "hospitals"."id" = ? AND "appointments"."id" = ? AND "patients"."id" = 1  [["id", 1], ["id", 1]] .You get nil when no data is found for the given conditions.